# PHP Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, windows, apache, pear, chmod

I start with PHP, wampserver and Composer on windows 10 and it will be a week that I can not fix this problem: When I type:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -d display_errors = 1 public/
```

on the browser by running: "localhost:8000/test", I have this error:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown
>   on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'public/' (include_path
>   = '.;C:\wamp64\bin\php7.1.9\pear') in Unknown on line 0

I installed the famous "pear", I modify the access mode to my project with:

```
chmod -R 777 or 755 myFramework
```

I even touched **php.ini** in apache folder and in php folder to add this line :

```
include_path
= '.;C:\wamp64\bin\php7.1.9\pear'
```

But nothing is working ! Can you help me ?

Comment: How did you do `chmod -R 777` on windows? (And you shouldn't set 777. That gives everyone total access to do anything).

Comment: i think it because i already installed git bash. It brings some linux commands in windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command line is wrong.

From `man php` or from [the PHP CLI online Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) :

- First

  > --define foo[=bar]
  >
  > -d foo[=bar]   Define INI entry foo with value bar

(note that there is no space before and after the `=` sign)

- Second

  > --docroot docroot
  >
  > -t docroot     Specify the document root to be used by the built-in web server

(you need to specify the document root with the `-t` parameter)

So, the final command will look like this :

```
php -S localhost:8000 -d display_errors=1 -t public/
```

And it should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you ! it was the '-t' parameter. It works well now !

Comment: @Casison_7 You're welcome. Please consider validate and upvote this answer if it solved your issue. Good luck. ; )

Answer (score -1):

If you are on an IBM i (v7r3, v7r4, v7r5) do the following:
===>  CHGSECAUD  F4 to add *AUTFAIL
===> CPYAUDJRNE ENTTYP(AF) OUTFILE(QGPL/QAUDITAF) JRNRCV(*CURCHAIN) FROMTIME(MMDDYY HHMMSS) TOTIME(MMDDYY HHMMSS) <<< Adjust the time and date range

Run this SQL command:
select * from QGPL.QAUDITAF

column AFPNM will have the IFS path having the authority issue.